How to Use Google OAuth Access Token to Open an Authenticated Google Maps Session Using Playwright
I am working on a Node.js application that uses Playwright to automate interactions with Google Maps. The goal is to use a previously obtained Google OAuth access_token and id_token to open a browser session that is already authenticated, allowing the user to access Google Maps without needing to log in manually.
I have successfully obtained the access_token and id_token using Google OAuth 2.0 and stored them in a database. However, when I attempt to inject these tokens into the browser session and navigate to a Google Maps URL, the session is not recognized as authenticated, and Google still prompts for login.
export const authenticateUser = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { userId } = req.body;
  let browser: Browser | null = null;
  let page: Page | null = null;

  try {
    // Retrieve user authentication info from DB by userId to get the placeID and tokens
    const userAuth = await ReviewAuth.findOne({ userId: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) });
    if (!userAuth) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Authentication info not found for the given userId' });
    }

    const { idToken, accessToken, placeID } = userAuth;
console.log(`Access token: ${accessToken}`);
    // Launch browser
    browser = await chromium.launch({
      headless: false,
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--enable-webgl',
        '--disable-web-security',
        '--disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process',
        '--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled',
      ],
    });
    page = await browser.newPage();

    // Set the access token or idToken as cookies in the Google domain context
    await page.context().addCookies([
      {
        name: 'id_token',
        value: idToken,
        domain: '.google.com',
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
      },
      {
        name: 'access_token',
        value: accessToken,
        domain: '.google.com',
        path: '/',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: true,
      },
    ]);

    // Navigate to Google's OAuth-protected endpoint to trigger session recognition
    await page.goto(placeID, { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });

    // Wait for a few seconds to let Google process the session
    await page.waitForTimeout(5000);

    // Check if the session is authenticated by looking for a user-specific element
    const isLoggedIn = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return !!document.querySelector('div[aria-label*="Google Account"]');
    });

    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      throw new Error('Failed to establish a recognized session with Google.');
    }

    // Navigate to the desired Google Maps place URL
    await page.goto(placeID, { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Authenticated and navigated successfully!' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error during authentication:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to authenticate and navigate.' });
  } finally {
    if (browser) {
      setTimeout(async () => {
        await browser!.close();
      }, 60000); // Close the browser after 60 seconds
    }
  }
};

And Database Body
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "67050db8aa6f1dbb46198091"
  },
  "userId": {
    "$oid": "67050db8aa6f1dbb4619808f"
  },
  "accessToken": "ya29.a0AcM612weGlAXSy-9MPzHN84C9VTNeXCHtsfoueYq3_IS-cyygFUvIPpS3NeffdHBYsHEs-*************",
  "refreshToken": "1//03m1tFk7Hk8OJCgYIARAAGAMSNwF-************",
  "idToken": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjI4YTQyMWNhZmJlM2RkODg5MjcxZGY5MDBmNGJiZjE2ZGI1YzI0ZDQiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRw**************",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2024-10-08T10:47:20.861Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2024-10-08T10:49:28.347Z"
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "placeID": "https://www.google.com/maps/place/RevCall/@36.8126665,10.1028039,863m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x12fd33ded55c334b:0xce8ee81658eef5c2!8m2!3d36.8126665!4d10.1053842!16s%2Fg%2F11wfdjrq_5?entry=ttu&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MTAwMi4xIKXMDSoASAFQAw%3D%3D"
}

Issue:
Despite setting the id_token and access_token as cookies for .google.com and navigating to

https://www.google.com/maps/place/RevCall/@36.8126665,10.1028039,863m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x12fd33ded55c334b:0xce8ee81658eef5c2!8m2!3d36.8126665!4d10.1053842!16s%2Fg%2F11wfdjrq_5?entry=ttu&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MTAwMi4xIKXMDSoASAFQAw%3D%3D

to trigger session recognition, the session is not recognized as authenticated. Google still prompts for user login when I try to access Google Maps.
What I've Tried:
Setting the id_token and access_token as cookies.
Navigating to

https://www.google.com/maps/place/RevCall/@36.8126665,10.1028039,863m/data=!3m2!1e3!4b1!4m6!3m5!1s0x12fd33ded55c334b:0xce8ee81658eef5c2!8m2!3d36.8126665!4d10.1053842!16s%2Fg%2F11wfdjrq_5?entry=ttu&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MTAwMi4xIKXMDSoASAFQAw%3D%3D

to see if Google recognizes the session.
Adjusting browser launch arguments to disable security features that might block session creation.
Questions:
Is it possible to simulate an authenticated session with Google Maps using the id_token or access_token in this way?
Are there other methods to leverage id_token or access_token to create an authenticated session in a Playwright browser?
Is there a way to bypass Google's login prompts for this use case without user interaction?
Additional Information:
Node.js with Playwright for browser automation.
Using OAuth 2.0 with passport-google-oauth20 for obtaining tokens.
Trying to avoid using direct page.fill for user login due to restrictions.
Any guidance or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated!
